# How to remove Machine names display in TFS Application tiers

Tags: tfs-2015

I am currently building Non Production TFS 2015 environment. I am restoring database including DBs from production to the new QA DB instance. I performed DB restore using TFSRestore.exe. The restore work successfully.

In TFS QA then I install Application Tier and configure to TFS QA and TFS QA service account.

Then I did RemapDBs, Reset Owner, RegisterDB then start the service. Then I change the Notification URL to point to QA TFS Url.

What is strange is that I can see that in Applications Tiers, I can see 2 machine names display. One is TFS Prod machine and TFS QA Machine Name. How I can remove Production TFS machine name under Application Tier section.

I check the checkbox "Filter out machines that have not connected in more than 3 days"

After 3 days the TFS Prod machine is remove from the Application Tier section. Since I want to do inplace upgrade to the next version therefore is it safe to do this?, how do I know this would not impact the TFS Prod?

I did run the 
TFSConfig ChangeServerID /SQLInstance:SPTEST\Contoso /DatabaseName:Tfs_Configuration /ProjectCollectionsOnly

as result, it created new hostID (Guid Number) inside TFS_configuration.tbl_ServiceHost. However, when I select a project in Team Foundation Server I receive an error `TF31001: Cannot connect to Team Foundation Server at Project1. The server returned the following error. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: service Definition`

Resolve this by delete anything under cache folder
c:\users[username]\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

This is similar post
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0ba7caad-4210-4991-b6f0-d4f1dd8c409b/removing-application-tier-server

Comment: Have you reconfigured the server ID? you need to reconfigure it.

Comment: Is there any record in DB where server ID recorded?. I did query tbl_ServiceHostProcess and it only records the QA server

Comment: Based on the officual documents, the records should be included in all the DBs. whatever, you can have a try with the command [ChangeServerID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#changeserverid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, your scenario should be [Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware)

> **(Clone option) Reconfigure server IDs and remap databases**:
>
> Perform the next set of steps on the new application-tier server if
> you intend to continue using the original TFS instance. These steps
> are necessary to avoid the risk of corruption of one or both
> deployments. If both servers are live, you could end up with
> corruption, particularly if they are pointing to the same SharePoint
> or reporting resources.

So, please try to [Reconfigure server IDs and remap databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware#clone-option-reconfigure-server-ids-and-remap-databases). If that still not work, I'm afriad that you have to remove the DB instance and reconfigure the QA envrionment step by step following the instruction mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware).

---

**UPDATE:**

Seems you just [restored an application-tier server](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-application-tier-server) but not [Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware)

For restoring an application-tier server, the name of the old application-tier server remains there is expected (See the end of [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-application-tier-server).).

> **Note:** The name of the old application-tier server will still appear in
> the list of application-tier servers in the administration console for
> Team Foundation. If you select the Filter out machines that have not
> connected in more than 3 days check box, the old server will disappear
> from the list within three days.

So, to avoid showing the old App Tier machine name you need to follow the steps to [Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware) as I mentioned in the original answer.

> **Note:** You must install but not configure TFS on the new data-tier
> server, and then use the restore function in the Scheduled Backups
> node

Comment: Sorry i need to undo the acceptance answer since it does not resolve my current issue. Every time i did the restore DB from Prod i still have the same problem. Even after running TFSConfig ChangeServerID

Comment: @Supermode Seems you just [restored an application-tier server](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-application-tier-server) but not [Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware).  See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting this issue. I followed all the cloning steps to move to my new TFS boxes, and I got it up and running, after running the command TFSConfig ChangeServerID.
But on the new server, under Application Tier > Application Tiers, I see two servers. 
The new SQL box, and the old TFS box!
This is on TFS 2017.